# CSS Shadow gets hidden because of carousel

Tags: css, carousel

I have a sidebar on left side which is at fixed position and having a box shadow on its right. And inside the right content part I have embedded bootstrap carousel. When my carousel comes in viewport it hides the shadow from left. What Can I do to fix this up?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to apply a z-index css propriety to your sidebar, with a big value ?